# Unable to retain the position of circle after zooming over a image in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to draw a image and a circle on the image using Fabricjs library.
I am following these steps :
1) Draw the image on the canvas.
2) Draw Circle on the canvas.
3) Use mouse to scroll to zoom in/out the image.

Problem :
I am able to zoom and that works perfect for image but the position of circle changes , for instance if I keep the circle by dragging it on the image(Panda's eyes ,for example) and the zoom in/out, the position of circle gets displaced from eyes to some other place.

Here's the code :

HTML:

```
<h1>After Zooming the shapes positions are changing<h1>
<canvas id="canvas" height=700 width=700></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://www.nairaland.com/attachments/1539614_pow_jpegfbbdd74848f20f626bb76cedb0cdded3', function(oImg) {
        oImg.scale(1.0).set({
        left: 1,
        top: 1,
        selectable : false
    });

    canvas.add(oImg).setActiveObject(oImg);
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: 100,
        top: 80,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        radius: 45,
        angle: 0,
        fill: '',
        stroke:'red',
        strokeWidth:3
    });

    canvas.add(circle);
    canvas.renderAll();

    _applyZoom();

});

var _applyZoom = function () {
    canvas.on("mouse:move", function(event) {
    currentMouseY = Math.round(event.e.clientY );
});

canvas.getObjects()[0].on("mousemove", function(event) {
    currentMouseX = Math.round(event.e.clientX );
});

var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"
if (document.attachEvent) 
  document.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, _zoom) 
else if (document.addEventListener) 
  document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, _zoom, false)
return this;

}

function _zoom(e, dragDelta) {  
    var evt=window.event || e;
    var delta = (dragDelta == undefined) ? evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta : dragDelta;
    var factor = 0.9;
    if (delta > 0) {
        factor = 1/factor;
    }
    var objects = canvas.getObjects();
    var image = objects[0];
    var imageX = (currentMouseX - image.getLeft()),
        imageY = (currentMouseY - image.getTop());
    var dx = imageX * (factor - 1),
        dy = imageY * (factor - 1);

    //applying zoom values.
    for (var i in objects) {
        objects[i].left = objects[i].left - dx;
        objects[i].top = objects[i].top - dy;
        objects[i].scaleX = objects[i].scaleX * factor;
        objects[i].scaleY = objects[i].scaleY * factor;
        objects[i].setCoords();
    }

    canvas.renderAll();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;

}
```

[Fiddle for the work](http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/gnfe3owf/11/)!

Comment: I've added the code from Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KarlGjertsen

Answer (score 1):

the main problem is on the for loop , when you try to give new dimensions to your objects.

i changed the for loop and it's fine

```
 for (var i in objects) {
       var scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
            var scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
            var left = objects[i].left;
            var top = objects[i].top;

            var tempScaleX = scaleX * factor;
            var tempScaleY = scaleY * factor;
            var tempLeft = left * factor;
            var tempTop = top * factor;

            objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
            objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
            objects[i].left = tempLeft;
            objects[i].top = tempTop;

            objects[i].setCoords();
    }
```

[fiddle live](http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/gnfe3owf/13/)

hope helps, good luck.

Comment: It works and can only satisfy developers but think in terms of end user . Is the zoom happening correctly? In your fiddle , it is zooming from top left but in my fiddle see the zoom functionality. Anyway thanks for your answer and time